# Disabling TLS 1 & 1.1 kills Biztalk 2016 fp3 with MSDTC on SQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We are mandated to harden the TLS/SSL and use TLS 1.2.

Upgrading Biztalk to 2016 fp3 should default to TLS 1.2 and it does - for outging traffic. The problem is that I cannot get MSDTC to call back with TLS 1.2.
If TLS 1.0 and 1.1 is disabled for Incoming on the biztalk server BT does not start.

I am unable to find any information on this.

Comment: Have you checked https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51476.biztalk-configure-tls-1-2-on-biztalk-server.aspx ?  TLS 1.2 is supported on all versions of SQL Server 2016 so it should just be a matter of upgrading the SQL client that Biztalk is using.

Comment: Yes, only that the traffic not working with only TLS 1.2 seem to be SQL (MSDTC) => BT server. BT => SQL is working with 1.2 
I am not sure how the client thing is working. I will loook into that. 2016 fp should default to TLS 1.2 but maybe something else is installed. since before. 
I am coming back to this issue after a couple a months, I am thinking I should by giving it one more attempt in case I missed something. No information should indicate that this is a none issue.

Comment: How do I know what SQL client is using?  Native client  is not installed.

What I did find is that BT fp3 was not installed as I requested. Trust but verfify....I think fp3 is needed.

Comment: Look at results of `select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions` and find the BT sessions, and check the  client_interface_name column.

Comment: Thanks,
client_version 7 for .Net SqlClient Data Provider and version 4 for OLEDB - based on the BT login_name.

Comment: Ok, now we are talking. I am attempting to upgrade to FP3 myself and it requires the native client. So it probably comes down to the wrong version. Thanks so far

Comment: installing fp + native client 2016 shifted all sessions to client_version 7. I hope that is enough.